# How to use a plugin in the QGIS 3.4 toolbox

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I have version 3.4 of QGIS and I want to generate a model, so I need SCP tools (unsupervised classification). I can not find a way to add it to the tool box in order to finish my working model.

Comment: These plugin installation docs might help: https://semiautomaticclassificationmanual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: Hello thank you, the plugin could install it correctly but I'm wanting to add it to an automation model and within the tools that it offers are not those of SCP. Try with the ones that I offer as SAGA and GRASS but it does not work for me (and in others they do not work for me) for the images that I need to classify

Comment: It looks like this plugin is not accessible through the model builder. It does have its own batch processing mode, though. So you can write a model that does everything else, then run the SCP tool manually.

Comment: Of course, the issue is that there are more than 600 images and the idea is to automate that process. Any possible suggestions? I accept any idea to try.